# Zenity Scrolling in Forms Dialog

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, zenity

I am creating a system in bash that uses zenity which creates a very long forms dialog. This dialog is large enough that it does not fit on the screen and it would appear that there is no way of scrolling down, hence the user cannot fill out all the forms, let alone press OK. Is there any way to, in zenity, allow the user to scroll up and down in a forms dialog?

Comment: Can you not make it into multiple dialogs?

Comment: I could, but I would prefer not to...

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't forms doesn't support scroll, so you're gonna have to.